# Dynamic expansion of a Crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report consisting of several pages. Each page consists of a several fields that are populated from database.

Suppose the following example :

```
Name : aaaaaa
Education Background:bbbbbbb
Age:cc
```

In my case the Education Background's details (bbbbbbb here) may consist of several words or several pages. If I set a large space for it, it will waste a big space on report (Yes. May be a paper) in a case of short answer.

How can I eliminate this problem? Does crystal reports provide a way to dynamically expand the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem.  Assuming these fields are in the Details section,

1. Create some Details subsections and move your fields into them (Report->Section Expert->Insert). In your example, you would have "Name" in "Details A", "Education Background" in "Details B", and Age in "Details C".
2. Right click on the Education Background field and go to Format Field->Common->Can Grow.
3. Make sure that in the design view, all subsections are at the minimum height needed to hold the fields.

Sounds complicated when I write it out like that, but it's not.