# Crystal Report height when I have grown field in the details section

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using vb.net 2008,i have fields that can grow, so as you can see in the picture, in the last row , the field can grow but not the section as the same as the above row. how i can fix this please.

[image]
**Update 1 :**

[image]

**Update 2 :**
[image]

**Update 3 : The Design >>>**

[image]
**The Result >>>**

[image]
 ===============
Update 4 :
I found a workaround and its better so far, so i just moved the bottom line of  the details section to the Group Footer at the bigening, and its worked fine, but if the details section has more than 2 page, the end of the non-last page (the last row in the page) is not closed as u can c in the result2 below, but still better than before.

*** Design:
[image]

*** Result 1 (when the report is one page)
[image]

*** result 2 when the report is more than page as u c at the end of the report is not closed, but as i said its better than how it was before.

[image]

Comment: Is it a cross tab or it is a different section? How have kept borders

Comment: it is not a crosstab, just the details section with dataset fields.

Comment: How about boarders?

Comment: the border is a box with lines

Comment: That is the issue......remone box and draw limes to section....

Comment: didn't work, the same problem

Comment: Ok create one more section and draw line in that section...limit the section height to fit theline exactly...let me know how it goes

Comment: :( sorry still the same

Comment: Can you show design

Comment: i updated my question, check the design mode

Answer (score 0):

When you want some columns to **grow** and you want lines to adjust to that dynamical height then you have to make it using 2 separated detail sections. So when report is rendering then it goes one section to another, so if you have **detail section1** and **detail section2**, you put content in section1 and lines in section2, so lines will fit after content (in multiple rows) displays.

To summarize, right-click on detail section and `insert section below`. After that you will have `detail section a` and `detail section b`. All field which you wanna display put in `detail section a` and all lines put in `detail section b`. A little help in the picture below.

[image: Help picture]

For any further questions feel free to ask :)

EDIT :

Updated your problem.

[image]

Change box with columns so it start from detail section a and end in detail section b.

Comment: didn't work, check my update 2 in my question,am i doing right?

Comment: @OsamaGadour Updated my answer

Comment: please check my update 3, the design and the result.

Comment: Is field which can grow in detail section a? because it looks like its in group footer

Comment: yes it is in details section, i found a workaround and it worked for me, i will post the solution later.

Comment: Ok, the problem was with lines in wrong section, or you should put 3 sections and last one suppress. Waiting for your solution

Comment: The same result should be if you putted that line in the `detail section b`. Have you tried to make 3 detail sections(a,b and c), put field in detail a, put line in detail b and suppress detail c?

Comment: what is your crystal report version

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution. Its long time to do this, so may be my given option text is wrong.

Whatever your data which you want to expand based on data, Just create another detail (or footer) section (means break the same section into 2 sub-section by right click -> insert section. see link below) and put all your fields in that.

Then right click on section expert and select that subsection which you want to grow, tick 'Grow section' and just preview it.

[Insert Subsection](http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/2408)

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/index?rid=/library/uuid/302b0820-4702-2e10-4783-c1c209536380&overridelayout=true

Check this link to solve your issue:- [Dynamic expansion of a Crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942457/dynamic-expansion-of-a-crystal-report)

Comment: I don't have Grow Section option !